# GS Connect and KDE Connect not detecting devices

Tags: networking, ubuntu, android, connection

When I open GS Connect on my computer (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS) and KDE Connect on my phone (Motorola g(6) play, Android 9), neither of them detects the other. I am sure they are both connected to the same network (same Wi-Fi), and my computer can ping the IP address of my phone. Help anyone ?

EDIT: Solved. The problem was the firewall, and doing

```
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp
sudo ufw reload
```

did the trick.

Comment: The instructions mention that you should start the pairing from the phone.

Comment: That's what I do